# Not able to set the variable properly in For Loop in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on the Ionic Ecommerce App and I am checking the **out of stock** for the products using 0 or 1.

This is my **productdetails.ts**:

```
outofstockp: boolean = false;

for(var k in this.detailsp.msg)
{
  console.log(this.detailsp.msg[k].out_of_stock);
  if(this.detailsp.msg[k].out_of_stock === "1")
  {
    this.outofstockp = true;
    this.hassize = false;
  }
}
```

In this, `this.detailsp.msg` is the array containing products. So, that's why I have applied the loop for checking the products **outofstock**. `console.log(this.detailsp.msg[k].out_of_stock);` is giving me 3 outputs 1, 0 and 0 because I have 3 products but the problem is that it is seating `this.outofstockp = true;` for all the products.

This is my **productdetails.htm**l:

```
<ion-col *ngIf="hassize" style="padding: 0px;">
      <button [disabled]="!product.SelectedSize" class="mybtn11" (click)="addToCart(product)" ion-button small>
        Add to Cart
      </button>
</ion-col>

<ion-col *ngIf="outofstockp" style="padding: 0px;">
    <button disabled class="mybtn11" ion-button small>
      Out Of Stock
    </button>
</ion-col>
```

In this, I have used 2 buttons, if the product is **outofstock** it will the **outofstock** button, otherwise it will show the **addtocart** button. But the problem is that it is showing **outofstock** button for all the products because my condition is running properly.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to have this logic in your ts file. You can easily handle this in your html file.
Assuming you are already looping through the product array in your **template(.html)** and in each iteration you get a product object. Since your ts file indicates that your product object has a property called out_of_stock, you can use that property directly in the html.

Something like this,

```
<ion-col *ngIf="product.out_of_stock == '0'" style="padding: 0px;">
      <button [disabled]="!product.SelectedSize" class="mybtn11" (click)="addToCart(product)" ion-button small>
        Add to Cart
      </button>
</ion-col>

<ion-col *ngIf="product.out_of_stock == '1'" style="padding: 0px;">
    <button disabled class="mybtn11" ion-button small>
      Out Of Stock
    </button>
</ion-col>
```

If you want to handle this in TS file only, then you need to consider using Key,Value where in your Key will be your product id or the product object, and Value would be an array containing outofstockp,hassize values for each product. But i suggest you not to do this, since you have the easiest way to achieve your result in the template.

Comment: Okay. So, this will work or not. <ion-col *ngIf="product.out_of_stock ? '0' : '1' " style="padding: 0px;">

Comment: Thank you bro for the answer. it has solved my query.

Comment: Sometimes we go for the difficult code and it has some code short code for the problem.

Comment: Please make the answer as right answer if you find it helpful and correct :)

Comment: Once again. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`this. outofstockp = true` is re-updated in each loop , you need to use *ngFor in the template and use an array instead of a single value , your code is buggy , please review your logic before asking such question

Comment: If I want to check in the ts file then.

Comment: create an array like this.outofstockfb[k] = false , outside the if and this.hassize[k] = true and inside the if update the value , then use this variable in the html file against ngIf like <div *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">{{outofstock[i]}}</div>

Comment: Thank you for the answer Bro.